# Starting a private conversation

Tags: discussion, private-messages

Is there a way to exchange contact data (for example the email address) with a user using a private channel? Sometimes I think that some user could become a friend and I don't know how to contact they. Of course this should only possible when the other user agrees.

Comment: According to this [link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57537/how-do-i-contact-other-users), private messaging is not available.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/433/222340. All that needs to be said is in there. In particular: "[I]f you want others to be able to contact you privately, add basic contact info to your profile's bio page."

Answer (score 3):

standard offer: I make my email address visible in my profile, if you and the other person email me I can forward initial messages in both directions, then bow out once it is working. If you cannot see my address search on  https://www.ams.org/cml/

Over the years, I have done this just a few times, it seems to work out.

Let's see: since I changed this to an answer, one may refer to this answer as part of the message (probably a comment addressed to the other party) suggesting the idea.

Saturday, 19 Sept.: that was different. Guy has a matrix question from a physics paper, not something I would be able to request. So he emailed me the paper as a pdf, I was able to confirm that his interpretation of the equation was correct, and I was able to answer the question. [A question about positive definite matrix decomposition](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1442410/a-question-about-positive-definite-matrix-decomposition)

Comment: Thank you for that offer. But isn't it somewhat strange that the system doesn't offer a possibility?

Comment: @principal-ideal-domain:  It is not strange in the context of the purpose of the Math.SE community as a repository of curated Questions and Answers on mathematical subjects at all levels, rather than a social networking site.  There is nothing wrong with social networking, but there are many other sites which address that kind of activity.

Comment: @hardmath I don't want to social network on this site with people. I just want to share contact information if both agree in a secure way that we can social network elsewhere.